# Automatically create nested elements with XStream

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I'd like to know if it's possible in XStream to automatically add a wrapper element without having to create a dummy object

Eg

```
class Patient {
   private HumanPatient humanPatient;
   //getters setters
}

class HumanPatient {
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
}
```

This needs to be serialized to xml as

```
<Patient>
  <HumanPatient>
    <FirstName></FirstName>
  </HumanPatient>
</Patient>
```

Ideally I'd just have `Patient` and skip `HumanPatient`

```
class Patient {
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   //getters setters
}
```

We do not need to concern ourselves with other sub elements of Patient besides HumanPatient and I don't want to create the hierarchy if I don't have to so Ideally I'd like xstream to serialize Patient with  and deserialize it as if it werent' there.

I have created a CustomConverter and I can do

```
 public class HumanPatientConverter implements Converter {


        @Override
        public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer,
                        MarshallingContext context) {
            writer.startNode("HumanPatient");
            writer.endNode();

        }

        @Override
        public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
            return Patient.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
        }
    }
```

However, then I have to control a bunch of serialization under that, it's got many nested things under `Patient` that I'd prefer to not control manually, I just want it to wrap everything under Patient with HumanPatient